# Extract first schema from search_path without quotes in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to extract the first schema from a postgres search_path using postgres itself. The actual function needs to work inside a larger SELECT as a condition in a WHERE clause:

```
SELECT * from something WHERE domain_hash = THEFUNCTION AND etc...
```

The search_path will always be something like:

```
"068503358dddd23c",spikeadmin
```

I'd like the function to return `068503358dddd23c` without the quotes.

I'm thinking a regular expression is probably in order?

Comment: Do you mean `THEFUNCTION()` as in a function call? Also, is the value you're looking for also the user name? That second part may seem like a strange question, but it seems like this schema name is probably related to the currently logged in user since you're implying it's variable.

Comment: The schema is variable but comes from another database field that's related to the host name being accessed in a Rails app. By function I was being pretty loose, I was hoping that it could be solved with something like the accepted answer :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :) Unfortunately this is a condition on a has_one in a Rails model and for some reason when I tried to pass in the domain hash that I'd gotten from within Rails itself (via it's schema_search_path method) it was trying to call it at strange times when the search_path wasn't ready to be read as it didn't have the right information in it. Pretty confusing really and I never got to the bottom of it, but figured that the DB knows what the search path is at the time the proper query is called and that's worked out pretty well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that PostgreSQL has a `quote_ident` function but no appropriate unquote function. And `"068503358dddd23c"` is the output of `quote_ident`.

So you can do something else:

```
SELECT * FROM something 
    WHERE 
        quote_ident(domainhash) = split_part(current_setting('search_path'), ',', 1)
        AND /* whatever */
```

This won't work if a schema has `,` in it. But for hexcodes this should be not a problem.

Comment: That's great! Yea I have to manually quote the hash as a schema name because they can start with numbers, so just quoting the other side works well. The schema will always be a hexcode and always be quoted.